# Trying to improve performance by removing DLookUp - Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

could anybody possibly give me some pointers as to the appropriate method to use here.

-Edit

I have fields in a form that relate to a users 'risk address', and I have a checkbox that updates the values in these fields that if selected loads the 'contact' details (from the table tblInsPersDet) into these fields.
If the checkbox isnt selected the user can enter new details.

I run the below sub routine on celection of the checkbox. To get the field values i'm using Dlookup, but i believe this to be inefficient? As it queries the database/table each time.

```
Public Sub sameAsContact(frm As Form)

frm.riskAddress1 = DLookup("[add1]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskAddress2 = DLookup("[add2]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskAddress3 = DLookup("[add3]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskAddress4 = DLookup("[add4]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskAddress5 = DLookup("[add5]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.cmbRiskCountry = DLookup("[country]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskDstToProp = DLookup("[distToProp]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskInsCompany = DLookup("[insCompany]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskPolNo = DLookup("[polNo]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskBldSi = DLookup("[bldSi]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskContSi = DLookup("[contSi]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskExcess = DLookup("[excess]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskOgLinkMort = DLookup("[linkMort]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)
frm.riskOgAddOn = DLookup("[addOn]", "tblInsPersDet", "[ID] =" & frm.insuredId)

End Sub
```

Is there a way to query the database once? Could anybody please give me a pointer as to a more appropriate method to get the data from the required record.

Thanks in advance for any help
Cheers
Noel

Comment: As a matter of curiosity, why do you set all your questions to community wiki?

Comment: aren't you suppossed to?! Doesn't this alow people to edit the question?

Comment: It is not the usual thing, and it means that you do not benefit from votes for a good question, but it is up to you.

Comment: If the result is a better question, with possibly better answers, it's worth the trade off. Cheers for the advice though.

Comment: BTW anyone with a reputation of >=2000 can edit other people's posts, whether or not the post is a community wiki.

Comment: oh right! May leave it off in the future.

Comment: Excessive use of DLookup is an indication of design errors, either in your schema or in the recordsources. DLookup is Excel-like thinking (it's like VLookup in Excel, in a certain sense), whereas you should be thinking in terms of sets retrieved via SQL. If it belongs on a form, it should probably be in the Recordsource of the form. If it's in a related table, then it is likely appropriate for a subform. This is all basic Access 101.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a subform that has insuredId as the Link Master field and ID as the Link Child field.

EDIT re note

I still believe you can use a subform. If the checkbox is ticked, either select the relevant record for the subform:

```
Me.MySubformControlName.Form.RecordSource="Select * From tblInsPersDet Where ID=" _
 & Me.txtinsuredId
```

Or fill a value into a hidden or visible field called, say, txtinsuredId.

If the checkbox is not checked, you can move to a new record in the subform.

EDIT re note #2

If you must use something akin to DlookUp, use a recordset:

```
 Set rs=CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("Select * From tblInsPersDet Where ID=" _
 & Me.txtinsuredId)

 For each fld in rs.Fields
    frm("txt" & fld.name)=fld
 Next
```

or there abouts.

Comment: Hi Remou, I've edited my question as I do not believe I was completely clear as to what the check box is achieving. I don't think I can use a subform in this instance?

Comment: I still think that a subform is the solution you need.

Comment: I see now how this solution would work. Time restraints may make it tricky to implement, as as far as i see it, i would need to restructure the database from the way I have it organised at present. But I certainly see how this would be effective.

Comment: The recordset solution could be more effective for me in this instance, will research this as it looks the way to go. Cheers

Comment: For what it's worth, you seem to be really fighting against all the natural methods of doing things in Access, but it could be that you're in this boat because your table design is completely wrong -- not enough information.

Comment: Yes, I think i will have to address this problem in my table design now rather than suffer later.
I think i can see the error of my ways, thanks for the advice chaps